# Managing sudden peak in traffic for event ticketing system

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, performance, apache-2.4, redis

I am going to be managing an event ticketing system for a specific event. I think we will probably be expecting generally low traffic, although there's likely to be a few sudden peaks of traffic (to up to 1000 visitors trying to purchase tickets concurrently) when the ticket sales open. The event previously had their web server crashed so we would like to avoid this happening again.

I'm thinking of having it hosted on Amazon, with 1 Apache (possibly with a front-end Nginx proxy) + Redis server for serving requests and 1 MySQL server for backend database. The 2 servers would probably each be using a micro instance. The ticketing system will probably be in-house, built with Laravel with the information frequently accessed (e.g. ticket sales count, form submission content) stored in Redis for rapid access. Is this good enough to deal with such volume of expected traffic? Would this be an over-kill for such volume? What form of optimisation should I should doing to the web and database server?

Answer (score 1):

Design questions aren't really what SF is about, however I'll answer as I'm an Amazon architect.

I don't think micro instances will do what you need, but it depends on your performance testing results. Write your software to scale across multiple servers behind an ELB, keeping session state in mind, and assuming individual servers will stop working at any time. Your performance / load testing will tell you how many of which servers you need. You can auto scale to set up new instances, but that might not be fast enough, so you should schedule or manually start instances when you expect high load. If you use a load balancer you can easily have micro instances running most of the time, then add larger instances for expected high load, shutting down the micro instances.

Use Amazon RDS, aka hosted MySQL, rather than running a server. It's easier, and probably faster, unless you need something RDS doesn't offer. Again you'll want to load test instance types.